# Excel index function that includes duplicate values

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, automation

I am attempting to index a full list of clients with their contract information based on the type of contract, to then automatically populate in another tab. I currently have a formula that will index the clients and if they have an "X" type of contract then the client name will appear in the first column, if not it will be blank. Now in the column next to that, I am attempting to consolidate the list by removing all blanks from that list. All formulas I have attempted to write are able to do this but don't keep duplicate values. So if there are multiple contracts with the same client appearing in the reference list then it will only appear once in the consolidated list.

Below is what I need: B to appear in the consolidated list twice because we have 2 contracts with client B.

[image]

`=IFERROR(IF(Contracts!H3="X",Contracts!A3,""),"")` --> This is the formula used to create the Long List where blanks are included.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$2000,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$1:$A$2000)>0,ROW($A$1:$A$1999),""),ROW(A1))),"")` --> This is the formula I have been using to create the consolidated list but it will not return duplicates, which I need it to.

I need this to be automated by a formula so no filtering and searching need be done by a person and it will auto-populate all clients with X type of contract (including duplicates if we have multiple contracts with the client) on a separate tab.

Comment: Could you share some sample data (as text) and the desired result (as text, or screenshot) for that sample data? Also, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Fixed the post to include a screenshot of desired results. First two columns would be on tab1 and second 2 would be on tab2. Excel 2016 i believe.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate combined with Index can be used to filter out values of column A where the count of the value in column H is larger than 1:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$5)/(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$5,$H$2:$H$5)>1),ROW(A1))),"")`

In Office 365 this spills the result:
`=TOCOL(IFS(COUNTIF(H2:H5,H2:H5)>1,A2:A5),2)`